# What is the `accessKey` parameter of GM_registerMenuCommand() and how to use it?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I was looking at the [GM_registerMenuCommand](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_registerMenuCommand) function in Tampermonkey and I noticed a third parameter called `accessKey` and thought it is to pass a hotkey to trigger this command.

What's the format of the parameter passed and am I wrong in assuming this is what it does?

I couldn't find documentation on the parameter anywhere. 
Does anyone here ever used it before?

Comment: This is how it worked in GreaseMonkey https://wiki.greasespot.net/index.php?title=GM_registerMenuCommand&oldid=7473 
but apparently it was removed as per https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_registerMenuCommand 
"As of Greasemonkey 4.0, this method has been removed" 
Maybe that helps, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [syntax for that function is](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_registerMenuCommand):

> `GM_registerMenuCommand (menuName, callbackFunction, accessKey)`

- Where `accessKey`, if supplied, must be a single letter of the string passed-in as `menuName`.
  It is a menu "access key" used to [facilitate Good UI by adding keyboard-only support](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/keyboard-accessibility/).

From [Menu Design Guidelines](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/drop-down-menus/)<sup>(Number 8)</sup>:

> Dropdowns (both menus and boxes) should support not only mouse input, but keys as well. In dropdown menus, ***access keys* should enable users to quickly select a visible option without using the mouse.** In a dropdown box, users should be able to type a letter and quickly navigate to options starting with that letter.

<sup><sup>(Emphasis added.)</sup></sup>

Important: [***Access keys* are different from**, and in addition to, any ***command shortcuts* ("hotkeys")**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ui-copy/).

---

Here's a sample **working Tampermonkey script that illustrates the use:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _GM_registerMenuCommand demo
// @match    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024629/*
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    GM_registerMenuCommand
// ==/UserScript==

/*-- GM_registerMenuCommand (menuName, callbackFunction, accessKey)
*/
GM_registerMenuCommand ("Say Hello", helloFunc, "H");

function helloFunc () {
    console.log ("Say hello to my little script.");
}
```

If you install and run this via Tampermonkey you will see (click for larger image):

> [image: Tampermonkey screenshot]

---

#### Notes:

1. [Violentmonkey ignores the `accessKey` parameter, for now.](https://violentmonkey.github.io/api/gm/#gm_registermenucommand)
2. [Greasemonkey 4+ has borked this feature](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_registerMenuCommand).  [Per usual](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html).
3. You can [set **a keyboard command to activate the Tampermonkey icon/menu** in Chrome](https://gist.github.com/kba/6719dc03e6c75f1fc25f8fa34a2360d1#user-content-open-the-tampermonkey-menu-from-keyboard-shortcut).
4. Keyboard icon activation currently does not seem to work in Firefox, but [a workaround is scheduled for Firefox version 67](https://techdows.com/2019/02/firefox-67-keyboard-navigation-support-for-browser-toolbar.html).